# How to implement facebook authentification with python social auth?

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I followed this tutorial http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/ and I managed Google Auth to work but when I try to register as facebook user, `'http://localhost:8000/login/facebook'` calls `https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth` which returns error 500 - internal server error.

This is what I set in my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'social.apps.django_app.default',

    ...
)


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
   'django.core.context_processors.debug',
   'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
   'django.core.context_processors.media',
   'django.core.context_processors.static',
   'django.core.context_processors.tz',
   'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
   'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
   'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
   'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',

   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

in urls.py

```
   url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
   url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
```

and in https://developers.facebook.com/apps I created the new app, I added a new platform (website) which url I set to

`http://localhost:8000`

Is there something I forgot?

Comment: If I click login via facebook, I get redirected to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email&state=xxxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F%3Fredirect_state%3xxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxx

but no html is loaded, I opened chrome console and it said 500/ internal server error, i dont know where to find something more specific :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

You are trying to auth using your `loaclhost:8000` web address. Which FB doesn't support localhost address. So change your local host address to define domain.

Like

> domain.com:8000

Comment: yes, i figured it out yesterday but this is right answer :)